# mysqli_fetch_array() doesnot grasp the first row of the table from database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i am trying to learn PHP and MYSQL. I have created a database in phpmyadmin which has the following attributes:

```
database name = my_database

table name = users
```

The table has:

```
attributes (id,Name, Password, Phone Number)
```

A pictorial example of what I have looks like:

[image: blah]

The problem is I wrote a query in php that would select all the data from the table and display it using a loop. For some reason no matter how much data I add in my users table, the code always omits the first row of data and displays the rest of the users data.According to my code, the output should be each user name displayed with their id number, but the information of the first user is never shown, and the rest of the users are shown perfectly.Can someone please help me regarding this.

my code:

```
<?php

$counter=0;


 $mysqli=mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root','','my_database');
 if(mysqli_connect_errno())
 {
    echo'connection failed'; echo"<br>";
 }

else{
    echo"connection SUCCESSFUL";echo"<br>";
}

    $sq1="select * from users";
    //$sq1="SELECT `Name`, `Password` FROM `users` ORDER BY `id`";

    $res= mysqli_query($mysqli,$sq1);
    if($res)
    {
        echo"Database Query Successful";echo"<br>";

        $user_array= mysqli_fetch_array($res);
    //print_r($user_array);
    while($user_array=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res))
    {

        $user_id=$user_array["id"];
        $user_name=$user_array["Name"];
        //$user_phonenumber=$user_array["Phone Number"];

        echo'The user name is '.$user_name.' The id is '.$user_id;

    }



    }

    else
    {
        echo"Databse unsuccessful";
    }



 ?>
```

Comment: The first fetch_array call is retrieving the first result from your query, then the loop starts from the second result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you called `mysqli_fetch_array` before entering the loop , remove the following line:

```
$user_array= mysqli_fetch_array($res);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot... I simply did not realize i made such a bad mistake... Thank you very much for clearing it up!

Comment: @Grunged_teenspirit47 welcome, it happened to me before, I knew the answer when I read the title lol